# JQuery Hiding Prepend Elements

Tags: jquery, hide, prepend

I can't figure out how to hide prepend span tags. I have the following JQuery code that prepends span tags as error messages in a form:

```
$('.mcEmail').each(function() {
        var mcEmailCheck = $(this).val();
        var mcEmailRegex = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

        if(!mcEmailCheck.match(mcEmailRegex)) {
            mcResponse('- Incorrect Email format!', true);
            $(this).parent().prepend('<span class="mcCustResponse">- Incorrect Email format!</span>');
            $(this).addClass('mcError').fadeOut().fadeIn();
        }
    });
```

Then I try the following:

```
$('.mcCustResponse').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

The same is used for all other validation. The error messages show up fine. I can pretty much try anything on these span tags and nothing works. Can't hide, fade out, remove etc. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out. If I put the click event inside the function, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.mcCustResponse').live("click", function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

or

```
$('.mcCustResponse').bind("click", function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect and what I was looking to learn about.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of jquery are you using? You need to use `.live()` or `.on()` depending on the version. The problem is that your spans with class mcCustResponse don't exist when the page loads. The code block you have with `.click()` will only register events for the elements on the page at load time. You can make a function that will register events to all elements with class mcCustResponse now and in the future using `.live()` or `.on()`.

http://api.jquery.com/on/ - `.on()` jquery 1.7

http://api.jquery.com/live/ - `.live()` before 1.7

Answer (score 0):

What about creating the span first, then adding and manipulating it after:

```
var span = '<span class="mcCustResponse">- Incorrect Email format!</span>';
span.hide();
$(this).parent().prepend(span);

...

$(this).parent().find('span').show();
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Yes, this is a great idea. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help! Please consider marking the answer as correct if it has solved your problem...or at least an upvote! :)